# why do I get No such property error: T for class: groovysh_evaluate in gremlin neo4j dbpeida?

Tags: neo4j, dbpedia, gremlin

```
gremlin> g
==> neo4jgraph[EmbeddedGraphDatabase [/Users/0x90/Downloads/dbpedia4neo]]
gremlin> g.v(123214).map()
==> value=U http://dbpedia.org/resource/Huey_Lewis_and_the_News
gremlin> g.v(123214).map()
==> value=U http://dbpedia.org/resource/Huey_Lewis_and_the_News
gremlin> v = g.idx(T.v)[[uri:'http://dbpedia.org/resource/Huey_Lewis_and_the_News']].next() 
==> No such property: T for class: groovysh_evaluate
gremlin>
```

while do I get  `No such property: T for class: groovysh_evaluate` while following http://markorodriguez.com/:

```
gremlin> v = g.idx(T.v)[[uri:'http://dbpedia.org/resource/Graph_theory']].next()
==>v[26634]
gremlin> v.map()
==>name=graph theory
==>uri=http://dbpedia.org/resource/Graph_theory
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax in the blog post was for an older version of Gremlin[[1]](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/gremlin-users/M-yBPuaZ_Xo).

You may use something like:

```
g.idx("your_index_name")[[uri:"http://dbpedia.org/resource/Graph_theory"]]
```

[Here](http://gremlindocs.com/#methods/index-map-entry) is the document for the new syntax

Comment: To extend VolkanT's correct answer. Gremlin has been around for over 3 years now and versions have changed. Be aware of the version number in examples. The blog post you mention is using Gremlin 1.x. The version of Gremlin you are using is 2.x. Good luck.